# Can access to my server from LAN but not from NAT

Tags: networking, router, iptables

I have been trying to deploy a home-made server. My network consists of a router (Comtrend brand) and 2 pcs (A server laptop connected to eh0 and a netbook connected to WiFi).

The problem is that everytime I try to access to my external public IP I'm redirected to my routers internet address (192.168.1.1).

But if I access with directly with 192.168.1.132 I can see all my services published and use all the protocols. (**http, ssh, etc**).

What could I do? Is it a problem in the server configuration?

**Configuration:**

My server's ip is always **192.168.1.132**
My laptop receives diferent internal ips but this is not important
My router has a dynamic ip. Let's say X.X.X.X.

**Things I've already tried:**

**1.**
I have opened ports in my router. Right now I have:

```
http    80  80  TCP 80  80  **192.168.1.132**   ppp0.1   
ssh     22  22  TCP 22  22    192.168.1.132     ppp0.1
```

**2.**
I tried with `IPTABLES` by adding the two next rules:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.132:80
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -d 192.168.1.132 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Then:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -F
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the router's http management port to some port other than port 80 (like, port 8080 for example), in order to get the port forwarding to work, so that it forwards http requests on port 80 to your server at 192.168.1.132.

Comment: Thans for your answer MTI2935.
I tried this in my router: 

External Port Start: 80
External Port End: 6969
TCP/UDP
Internal Port Start: (80 / 6969) I've tried with both.
Internal Port End: 6969 
Server IP Address: 192.168.1.132

I changed my configuration in my apache so I can access now with both 80 and 6969 ports but always from 192.168.1.132.

I also added this to my iptables:

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.132:6969

No luck until now!

Comment: Can you try disabling iptables on the server (just temporarily) to see if that solves the problem?

Comment: I disabled everything with: 

sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

If I write iptables -L nothing appears so I think I don't have iptables enabled but the result is the same, I 'm redirected to 192.168.1.1 when I access to my public IP.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly - from outside of your LAN, when you point your browser to your router's public IP address, your are getting your router's web management UI, instead of your web server.  Is that correct?  If so, I'm thinking that having the router's web UI enabled (to the public) is preventing the port 80 forwarding from working.  Can you try disabling the router's web UI publicly (you can still keep it enabled on the private side).  Also, what kind of router is this?

Comment: Well I think I got the problem. My router doesn't have NAT LoopBack so I can't access from LAN. If I browser my public IP with my mobile phone I can see all my content. Would you know any solution for routers that don't have this loopback option or (NAT reflection)?

Comment: No, you shouldn't need NAT loopback for this to work.  From the public side of your router, you want to be able to access the web server on your LAN, by pointing a web browser to the public IP of your router, correct?  And, from the private side of your router, you want to be able to access your web server by pointing a browser to 192.168.1.132 (which is the private IP of your web server), correct?  If that's the case, then you do not need NAT loopback, just port forwarding to make the public connection on port 80 forward to 192.168.1.132.  What kind of router is it?

Comment: I can connect from both sides right now, but when I'm in my network LAN I have to change from my public IP to 192.168.1.132. That is the only inconvenient and as I've read there aren't to many solutions for this.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#NAT_loopback)

I'm under a Comtrend ar-5387ur that has no loopback for sure. Thank you MTI2935

Comment: OK, I see now.  Yes, from the LAN side, you would need to use the private IP of the server, 192.168.1.132, unless you have NAT loopback.